# getAllVisibleItems(), getAllItems returns items twice

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to do something really simple - get the items from an order. There seem to be three functions that Magento 1.7 provides for this.

- getAllItems() : This returns all items twice. The items returned
  are of type simple (not configurable)
- getItemsCollection() : Ditto
- getAllVisibleItems() : Ditto

Many of the answers that I've read elsewhere point to this problem being caused by 'parent' and 'child' products, but there are none in my DB. I've checked the tables that define the parent/child relationship and they are both empty.

Here's the code that I'm running :

```
        $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id, 'increment_id'); //load order by order id

        $ordered_items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        //$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
        //$ordered_items = $order->getItemsCollection();

        foreach($ordered_items as $item)
        {
            if($this->debug)
            {
                echo $item->getItemId()."</br>";
                echo $item->getProductId()."</br>";
                echo $item->getSku()."</br>";
                echo $item->getQtyOrdered()."</br>";
                echo $item->getName()."</br>";
            }

            echo("*************************************************</br>");

        }

And the output is 
6
934
1003
1.0000
ProductA
*************************************************
6
934
1003
1.0000
ProductA
*************************************************
```

As you can see the first figure outputted is the actual entity_id - so I'm getting real duplication of the *same* item?

Comment: I've just looked in sales_flat_order_item to confirm that this product has only one entry against the order_id

Comment: Where have you put your code ? Are you sure that this isn't the function that is actually called twice instead of the items being duplicated ?

Comment: Duhhhh.... you're absolutely right. Have just tested the code in isolation and the items only appear once. Still not sure where the error is, but it's not a problem with the Magento functions (of course not!)

Comment: Thank you - sorry to waste your time! If it's any consolation - you've  saved me a few hours of mine.

Comment: Maybe you must edit the title as [SOLVED]

Answer (score 6):

You have to use this code

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id, 'increment_id');
$_items = $order->getItemsCollection();

 foreach ($_items as $item) {
    if ($item->getParentItem()) continue;
    //do something
    echo $item->getSku();
}
```